# Scanner throws NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, string, substring, java.util.scanner

The following code is showing an error. I am very new to coding. This thing is messing with my head. What can I do?

I have tried everything I know but nothing has worked out so far. What is the best and most efficient way to code such programs?

> Exception in thread "main"
>
> java.util.NoSuchElementException at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)     at
>   Codechef.main(Main.java:27)

*The following code is after edit. But it is still showing the same error of NoSuchElementFound Exception.*

```
   public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner scan =  new Scanner(System.in);

        while (!scan.hasNext()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (RuntimeException ignored) {}

        System.out.println("Enter first name");

        String fName = scan.next();

        while(!scan.hasNext()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            }catch (RuntimeException ignored) {}
        }
        String lName = scan.next();

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
           try {
               Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (RuntimeException ignored) {}
        int id = scan.nextInt();

        int marks[] = new int[5];
        getInfo(fName, lName, id, marks);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: where does it say that? which line of your code? also, where did you get this code? the comment "/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */" makes no sense at all

Comment: I wrote this code. 

String fName = scan.next();

Comment: So what does that have to do with `substring` not working, as your title claims?

Comment: @Stultuske that comment make sense in context of [CodeChef](https://www.codechef.com/)

Comment: I am sorry. Stackoverflow asked to have a different title. That's why the title.

Comment: it would be nice if you provided the input you are typing

Comment: This code is just the replacement for 4 of your lines, from `Scanner scan... until ... scan.nextInt ();` Nobody can now understand your problem. Nobody knowns what line 27 is, where the error is thrown, since there are only about 25 lines in total. If I compile and run the code, and input 2 Strings and one int, I get an error in getInfo now.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any problem in your as you have mentioned.
You just need to do some refactoring and allow a popup to user to write first, last name and Id:
Try to add System.out.println("") before getting input from user.
Ex:
System.out.println("Enter First Name:");
String fName = scan.next();

Possible Root Cause:
When you are getting "ID" from the user, you have to provide INTEGER value there.